# python isn't accepting my variable

Tags: python

```
#dating sim
energy = 10
flirtpower = 5
print ('welcome to Paragonia dating simulator!')
print ('it is a sunny day at the end of the summer. You are new to
Paragonia Highschool.')
print ('A cute blonde boy walks up to you. he says:')
name = int (input ("what's your name?"))
print ('-Nice too meet you, ' name ,'! My name is Alex, Alex Snowdon.
He smiles at you.')
```

python says 'invalid syntax' and highlights the variable 'name'. What am I doing wrong? I'm a complete beginner...

Comment: You forgot a comma between the string before and `name`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a comma right before your variable `name`

```
print ('-Nice too meet you, ', name ,'! My name is Alex, Alex Snowdon. He smiles at you.')
```

Also, you are going to face another error because you are casting an input to an `int` that I think you want as an `str`:

Change this: `name = int (input ("what's your name?"))`

To:

```
name = input ("what's your name?")
```

A much easier way to write this to avoid issues like this is to use `format` on your string, and place `{}` where you want to place your variable:

```
print ('-Nice too meet you, {}! My name is Alex, Alex Snowdon. He smiles at you.'.format(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ('-Nice too meet you, ', name ,'! My name is Alex, Alex Snowdon. He smiles at you.')
#You forgot a comma here     ^, and you cannot put a string over multiple lines, 
unles you use triple-commas, like this:

"""This is a string
that goes over multiple lines."""
```

Comment: ahhh I forgot that! thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
print ('-Nice too meet you, ' name ,'! My name is Alex, Alex Snowdon.
He smiles at you.')
```

You forgot to put a come after '-Nice too meet you, ' [insert coma here] name,...